# Moving and deleting one word at a time using Ctrl + Arrow keys or Ctrl + Del

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I want to know if it's possible to delete a whole word or move around one word at a time when in INSERT mode, like in "regular" applications when pressing Ctrl and using the arrow keys jump one word at a time, or pressing Ctrl+DEL deletes a whole word.

Maybe plugins exist for this or plainly configuring .vimrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the word before the cursor in insert mode, you can type <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>.

Vim has a handful of other insert mode shortcuts, and these are documented at `:help ins-special-keys`, and `:help ins-special-special`. Note that Ctrl + left/right are already mapped by default, but they [don't necessarily work in all environments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11668/control-arrow-to-skip-over-text).

There are also a number of plugins that provide further such functionality in insert mode, e.g. [rsi.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi), [vim-emacs-bindings](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-emacs-bindings).